# for loop and files with spaces

Tags: linux, bash

Here is my command

```
for i in `find . -name '*Source*.dat'`; do cp "$i" $INBOUND/$RANDOM.dat; done;
```

Here are the files (just a sample):

```
/(12)SA1 (Admitting Diagnosis) --_TA1-1 + TA1-2/Source.dat
./(12)SA1 (Admitting Diagnosis) --_TA1-1 + TA1-2/Source_2000C.dat
./(13)SE1 (External Cause of Injury) --_ TE1-1+TE1-2/Source.dat
./(13)SE1 (External Cause of Injury) --_ TE1-1+TE1-2/Source_2000C.dat
./(13)SE1 (External Cause of Injury) --_ TE1-1+TE1-2/Source_POATest.dat
./(14)SP1(Primary)--_ TP1-1 + TP1-2/Source.dat
./(14)SP1(Primary)--_ TP1-1 + TP1-2/Source_2000C.dat
./(14)SP1(Primary)--_ TP1-1 + TP1-2/Source_ProcDateTest.dat
./(15)SP1(Primary)--_ TP1-1 + TP1-2 - SP2 -- TP2-1 + TP2-2/Source.dat
./(16)SP1(Primary)--_ TP1-1 + TP1-2 +TP1-3- SP2 -- TP2-1 + TP2-2/Source.dat
./(17)SP1(Primary)--_ TP1-1 + TP1-2 +TP1-3/Source.dat
./(18)SP1(Primary)--_ TP1-1 + TP1-2 - SP2 -- TP2-1 + TP2-2 - Copy/Source.dat
./(19)SD1 (Primary)+SD2 (Other Diagnosis)--_ TD12/Source.dat
./(19)SD1 (Primary)+SD2 (Other Diagnosis)--_ TD12/Source_2000C.dat
./(19)SD1 (Primary)+SD2 (Other Diagnosis)--_ TD12/Source_POATest.dat
./(2)SD3--_TD4 SD4--_TD4/Source.dat
./(2)SD3--_TD4 SD4--_TD4/Source2.dat
```

Those spaces are getting tokenized by bash and this doesn't work. 
In addition, I want to append some randomness to the end of these files so they don't collide in the destination directory but that's another story.

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) points to the loop and says "Use find -exec or a while read loop instead, as for loops over find will fail for filenames like 'my file*.txt'." It also [links to a page](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2044) with further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name '*Source*.dat' -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "$2/$RANDOM.dat"' -- {} "$INBOUND" \;
```

Using `-exec` to execute commands is whitespace safe. Using `sh` to execute `cp` is necessary to get a different `$RANDOM` for each copy.

Comment: 4 years later I now understand what this is doing - this is after having written thousands of lines of bash since then. I am revisiting this answer/question because I have the same situation again with a twist: I don't want a random name, I want the file to be named the same as the directory it was found in. like `dirname {}` but that sytax doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
find . -name '*file*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp {} $INBOUND/{}-$RANDOM.dat
```

`xargs` is a handy way of constructing an argument list and passing it to a command.

- `find -print0` and `xargs -0` go together, and are basically an agreement between the two commands about how to terminate arguments. In this case, it means the space won't be interpreted as the end of an argument.
- `-I {}` sets up the `{}` as an argument placeholder for `xargs`.

As for randomising the file name to avoid a collision, there are obviously lots of things you could do to generate a random string to attach. The most important part, though, is that you verify that your new file name *also* does not exist. You might use a loop something like this to attempt that:

```
$RANDOM=$(date | md5)
filename=$INBOUND/$RANDOM.dat
while [ -e $filename ]; do
  $RANDOM=$(date | md5)
  filename=$INBOUND/$RANDOM.dat
done
```

I'm not necessarily advocating for or against generating a random filename with a hash of the current time: the main point is that you want to check for existence of that file first, just in case.

Comment: This command seems to kinda work -- only 1 file is making it in the firectory

Comment: Ah. Oops. We need to have a different name for each file! As I had it written, every file was being copied to the same name. I've edited to include the argument placeholder `{}` and that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If all the files are at the same directory level, as in your example, you don't need `find`. For example,

```
 for i in */*Source*.dat; do
   cp "$i" $INBOUND/$RANDOM.dat
 done
```

will tokenize correctly and will find the correct files provided they are all in directories which are children of the current directory.

As @chepner points out in a comment, if you have bash v4 you can use `**`:

```
 for i in **/*Source*.dat; do
   cp "$i" $INBOUND/$RANDOM.dat
 done
```

which should find exactly the same files as `find` would, without the tokenizing issue.

Comment: `bash` 4 introduces the `**` operator, even if the files exist in subdirectories: `for i in **/*Source*.dat; do`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of treating files with spaces. You can use `find`in a pipe, while and read:

```
find . -name '*Source*.dat' | while read file ; do cp "$file" "$INBOUND/$RANDOM.dat"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
while read  i;do
  echo "file is $i"
  cp "$i" $INBOUND/$RANDOM.dat

done < <(find . -name '*Source*.dat')
```