# find + cp spaces in path AND need to rename. Howto?

Tags: bash

I need to find all files recursively with the name 'config.xml' and set them aside for analysis. The paths have spaces in them just to keep it interesting. However, I need them to be unique or they will collide in the same folder. What I would like to do is basically copy them off but using the name of the directory they were found in. The command I want is something like from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615524/for-loop-and-files-with-spaces) except I need it to do something like `$(dirname {})`. When I do that, nothing gets moved (but I get no error)

Sample, but non-functional command:
`find . -name 'config.xml' -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "$2.xml"' -- {} "$HOME/data/$(dirname {})" \;`

Comment: BTW, you really want `dirname`, not `basename`? Doesn't make much sense to me that you'd be wanting to create files named based on directory names rather than filenames.

Comment: the file names are all identical - the only difference is the directory they are in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with just one shell, not one per file found (as used by prior answers):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do 
  outFile="$HOME/data/${filename%/*}.xml"
  mkdir -p -- "${outFile%/*}"
  cp -- "$filename" "$outFile"
done < <(find . -name 'config.xml' -print0)
```

This way your `find` emits a NUL-delimited stream of filenames, consumed one-by-one by the `while read` loop in the parent shell.

(You *could* use `"$HOME/data/$(dirname "$filename").xml"`, but from a performance perspective that's really silly: `$()` `fork()`s off a subshell, and `dirname` is an external executable that needs to be `exec`'d, linked and loaded; no point to all that overhead when you can just do the string manipulation internal to the shell itself).

Comment: Ok, it works, but I get a lot of error output too (re: files I don't care about):
`cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/cbongiorno/data/./FF-Credit-US/branches/fb-pipeline.xml’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Edited to run `mkdir` to create destination directories when they don't exist -- any other solution requires more information about how you decide what you do and don't want to keep than is provided.

Answer (score 2):

You may use it like this:

```
find . -name 'config.xml' -exec bash -c \
'd="$HOME/data/${1%/*}/"; mkdir -p "$d"; command cp -p "$1" "$d"' - {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

`-exec sh` is a little hard to handle, but not impossible. The `$(dirname ...)` is expanded prior sh is run, so it's equal `dirname {}` - the dirname of file `{}`. Do something like `-exec sh -c ' .... ' -- {}` and put the `$(dirname ... )` inside sh script using `$1`.

```
find . -name 'config.xml' -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "$2/data/$(dirname "$1").xml"' -- {} "$HOME" \;
```

Comment: Nie działa dokładnie ale dałeś mi pomysły +1